How to check if a key is pressed 2 seconds in Unity3d in C#?
I am working on a game in Unity3d. How do I check that the key I press is pressed for a duration of 2 seconds in C# ?

get the time when the key is pressed, get the time when the key is released, subtract the two times.

and in your question you need to show what you have tried and where exactly you have a problem.

Start a timer on the key in question in the preview event ... to expire in 2 seconds. On key up, if the timer is still running, then stop it. Else, the timer (event) will fire after 2 secs, at which point you turn it off, and do whatever you wanted to do.

Set the wanted key in your editor.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class KeyTwoSeconds : MonoBehaviour
{
    public KeyCode key; // set the key in the inspector

    private float hold_time = 2f; // time required to hold the key in seconds
    private float hold_counter = 0f; // counter to track how long the key is held

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(key))
        {
            hold_counter += Time.deltaTime;

            if (hold_counter >= hold_time)
            {
                Debug.Log("You held " + key + " for 2 seconds");
                hold_counter = 0f; // reset after holding for 2 seconds, you can remove this, if you want this part to work every frame, until you let go of the key
            }
        }
        else
        {
            hold_counter = 0f; // reset if the key is released
        }
    }
}



this will trigger every 2s if the key is keep pressed
